# Не даёт результата функция setBackground() Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, gui

Цвет окна не меняется при использовании функции setBackground()

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class vusualInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame view = new JFrame("Dark Eldar");
        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        view.setLayout(null);
        view.setSize(1920, 1080);
        view.add(top);
        view.setVisible(true);
        view.setResizable(false);
        view.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        top.setBackground(new Color(85, 26, 139));

        JButton but = new JButton("Real-space raid");
        but.setBounds(750, 800, 150, 50);
        view.add(but);
    }
}
```

Не вижу ошибки в использовании этой функции

Comment: Попробуйте делать setBackground перед добавлением панели к JFrame, может помочь

Comment: @ЕльцовДанил Увы, не вышло... Ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас в коде несколько ошибок:
1. Отображение окна должно быть последним действием
2. Не тому компоненту Вы устанавливаете setLayout(null)
3. Вместо добавления кнопки на панель, добавляете ее на форму
4. Если же все таки хотите добавить именно на форму и панель и кнопку, то изучите менеджеры компоновки или воспользуйтесь менеджером для формы по умолчанию - BorderLayout.
Откорректировал Ваш код:

```
    public class SwingTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame view = new JFrame("Dark Eldar");
            JPanel top = new JPanel();
            top.setLayout(null);
            view.setSize(1920, 1080);
            view.add(top);
            view.setResizable(false);
            view.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            top.setBackground(new Color(85, 26, 139));

            JButton but = new JButton("Real-space raid");
            but.setBounds(750, 800, 150, 50);
            top.add(but);
            view.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!